# Creating random coefficients for linear equations in mathematica

Tags: random, wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to assign a random value to p1, p2, p3 and p4 for the following equation?

p1 y1 + p2 y2 + p3 y3 = p4

given that y1, y2 and y3 are variables to be solved.

Comment: do the co-efficients need to have a particular distribution? Normal? Uniform?

Comment: no, just random real or random integers

Comment: @penny: which probably means that you want a uniform distribution...

Answer (score 9):

The easiest(?) way is to `Thread` a list of random values over a replacement rule:

For example:

```
p1 y1 + p2 y2 + p3 y3 == p4 /. Thread[{p1, p2, p3, p4} -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, 4]]

(* 0.345963 y1 + 0.333069 y2 + 0.565556 y3 == 0.643419 *)
```

Or, inspired by Leonid, you can use `Alternatives` and pattern matching:

```
p1 y1 + p2 y2 + p3 y3 == p4 /. p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 :> RandomReal[]
```

---

Just for fun, here's one more, similar solution:

```
p1 y1 + p2 y2 + p3 y3 == p4 /. s_Symbol :> 
     RandomReal[]/;StringMatchQ[SymbolName[s], "p"~~DigitCharacter]
```

Where you could replace `DigitCharacter` with `NumberString` if you want it to match more than just `p0, p1, ..., p9`.  Of course, for large expressions, the above won't be particularly efficient...

Comment: +1. If using `Alternatives` as I suggested, you should use a delayed rule, or all the numbers will be the same.

Comment: @Leonid: oops... thought I did!

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are good, but if you do a lot of this sort of thing, I recommend naming your variables and coefficients in a more systematic way. This will not only allow you to write a much simpler rule, it will also make for much simpler changes when it's time to go from 3 equations to 4. For example:

```
In[1]:= vars   = Array[y, 3] 
Out[1]= {y[1], y[2], y[3]}

In[2]:= coeffs = Array[p, 4]
Out[2]= {p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4]}
```

You can be a little fancy when you make your equation:

```
In[3]:= vars . Most[coeffs] == Last[coeffs]
Out[3]= p[1] y[1] + p[2] y[2] + p[3] y[3] == p[4]
```

Substituting random numbers for the coefficients is now one one very basic rule:

```
In[4]:= sub = eqn /. p[_] :> RandomReal[] 
Out[4]= 0.281517 y[1] + 0.089162 y[2] + 0.0860836 y[3] == 0.915208
```

The rule at the end could also be written `_p :> RandomReal[]`, if you prefer. You don't have to type much to solve it, either.

```
In[5]:= Reduce[sub]
Out[5]= y[1] == 3.25099 - 0.31672 y[2] - 0.305785 y[3]
```

As [Andrew Walker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442349/creating-random-coefficients-for-linear-equations-in-mathematica/7442622#7442622) said, you use `Reduce` to find all the solutions, instead of just some of them. You can wrap this up in a function which paramerizes the number of variables like so:

```
In[6]:= reduceRandomEquation[n_Integer] := 
          With[{vars = Array[y, n], coeffs = Array[p, n+1]},
            Reduce[vars . Most[coeffs]]

In[7]:= reduceRandomEquation[4]
Out[7]= y[1] == 2.13547 - 0.532422 y[2] - 0.124029 y[3] - 2.48944 y[4]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need solutions with values substituted in, one possible way to do this is:

```
f[y1_, y2_, y3_] := p1 y1 + p2 y2 + p3 y3 - p4
g = f[y1, y2, y3] /. p1 -> RandomReal[] /. p2 -> RandomReal[] /. 
   p3 -> RandomReal[] /. p4 -> RandomReal[]
Reduce[g == 0, {y1}]
Reduce[g == 0, {y2}]
Reduce[g == 0, {y3}]
```

If all you need is the solution to the equations:

```
f[y1_, y2_, y3_] := p1 y1 + p2 y2 + p3 y3 - p4
g = f[y1, y2, y3]
Solve[g == 0, {y1}]
Solve[g == 0, {y2}]
Solve[g == 0, {y3}]
```

Comment: what is the reduce function for? is it necessary?

Comment: Reduce is similar to Solve, but will find all solutions. In this case solve would have been sufficient

Comment: @Andrew +1. Your solution could be somewhat simplified: `f[y1, y2, y3] /. p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 :> RandomReal[]`.

Comment: oh in fact, i dont want to solve the problem yet. i just need to get the equations out.

Comment: @Leonid - thanks for that simplification, new things to try! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you can live without the symbolic coefficient names p1 et al, then you might generate as below. We take a variable list, and number of equations, and a range for the coefficients and rhs vector.

```
In[80]:= randomLinearEquations[vars_, n_, crange_] := 
 Thread[RandomReal[crange, {n, Length[vars]}].vars == 
   RandomReal[crange, n]]

In[81]:= randomLinearEquations[{x, y, z}, 2, {-10, 10}]

Out[81]= {7.72377 x - 4.18397 y - 4.58168 z == -7.78991, -1.13697 x + 
   5.67126 y + 7.47534 z == -6.11561}
```

It is straightforward to obtain variants such as integer coefficients, different ranges for matrix and rhs, etc.

Daniel Lichtblau

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
dim = 3;
eq = Array[p, dim].Array[y, dim] == p[dim + 1];
Evaluate@Array[p, dim + 1] = RandomInteger[10, dim + 1]

Solve[eq, Array[y, dim]]
```